# Filtering telemetry from devices with multiple users in Azure IoT Central

Tags: azure-iot-central

Suppose that I have a device with multiple users. User 1 will start a session with the device, send some telemetry data over a period of time and eventually end their session. Next, User 2 will start a session and also send some telemetry data from the same device. In IoT Central, I am interested in generating telemetry analytics grouped by user, not by device. Is it possible to send a user ID string once at the start of every session to indicate to azure that the following telemetry data is for that user? What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you concerned with data isolation from user to use? If so, the best way to accomplish this is to delete and re-create a device instance (i.e. reprovision) the device when it gets moved from user to user; however this won't allow you to track device telemetry trends over time for the same device (i.e. battery life).

If you're not concerned with data isolation, you can send a device property that's unique per user and then be able to slice and dice the data by the device property. This won't be supported within the built-in analytics tool in IoT Central though. You can export the data using continuous data export and do the analysis offline (i.e. in PowerBI).